# Passing dynamic object to View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I decided to try avoid view models and pass dynamic data to views, here is the test code I wrote in my controller:

```
        dynamic model = new ExpandoObject();

        var user = unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get().First();

        model.Title = "Dynamic test";
        model.User = user;

        return View(model);
```

And in View:

```
@Model.Title
@Model.User.UserName
```

I like this method more because I don't have to write ViewModel class for every controller action, and also don't have to change ViewModel every time I decide to pass a new property to View.

The only downside I see is lack of intellisense in Views, because they are not strongly typed any more, but that doesn't seem as a big problem.

My question is, is there any other downsides of using this approach instead of ViewModels, because I am just starting a new project in my company, and I don't want to regret later if I use this approach...

Comment: Why not just use the controller's `ViewBag` and the view's `@ViewBag`? This is dynamic...

Comment: The obvious one is that any syntax error, even a casing diffrerence, won't be detected by the compiler. Debugging this will be hard, since the view will render but the mis-spelled elements will simply appear empty. Which of these empties is missing data and which the result of an error?

Comment: @DavidPine Nevermind, it is the same dynamic concept, my question is if there are any other downsides of not using view models and strongly typed views.

Comment: @DavidPine there is no real difference as far as this question is concerned. The disadvantages will be the same

Comment: @Aleksa Downsides of using ViewBag (dynamic) instead of ViewModels is your application will **throw run-time exceptions** which are not easy to catch. It is a nightmare for the maintenance phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the main advantage of creating view models is readability and resuseability of the code.

If I go to your piece of controller which you pasted, technically I can understand it, but I don't know what the model is about from business perspective. Of course you can name it more descriptive, but I don't believe it resolve the issue.

Second thing is reuseability, so I can imagine a lot of situation when multiple views can use the same model or some part of models and in this case you need to copy & paste code which creates you dynamic model or create some helper function which do this for you.

Basically I believe that it will be very painful when those dynamic models need to be changed e.g you removed some property in controller, but you forgot to do the same in some of the views. You won't be informed by compilator that something is wrong.

Additionally without strongly typed view model I believe there is no way to create attribute based model validation (which is very common business case)